# $routeProvider always redirecting to .otherwise statement in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am learning Angularjs and Setting my routing for pages. Right now when whatever Url I try the .otherwise statement is executed. here is my app.js

```
 var myNinjaApp = angular.module('myNinjaApp', ['ngRoute']);

myNinjaApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when ('/home',{
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    })
    .when ('/directory', {
        templateUrl: 'views/directory.html',
        controller :  'NinjaController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/directory'
    }); 
}]);
```

And the following is my index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myNinjaApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="app/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/angular.route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <header ng-include = "'header.html'"></header>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using vscode live server to run this simple app. Also, I have the the controller in my app.js but I haven't pasted the code over here for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

try this `<base href="/">` in you're header tag, and add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` before `$routeProvider`